# How to know pattern of string date in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, date, datetime, time, zoneddatetime

I want to convert in `ZonedDateTime`. How can I recognise pattern to pass in `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(????????)`.

```
val string = "May 9, 2020 8:09:03 PM"

private fun getFormatDate(date: String): ZonedDateTime {
     val dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(????????)
     return ZonedDateTime.parse(date, dateTimeFormatter)
}
```

Many Thanks

Comment: "May 9, 2020 8:09:03 PM" does not contain a timezone. What time zone do you want the `ZonedDateTime` to have?

Comment: I think default one.

Comment: You got given the solution but you will run into similar issues again. The real answer here is that you can find all patterns in the documentation, for example here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: @Tim you shouldn't be recommending a legacy class from the documentation of an obsolete, end-of-life, no-longer-supported version of Java. The right class to use is DateTimeFormatter.

Comment: Can you provide where is the new document?

Comment: Sweeper has provided a link to the new documentation already. Click on "See all the pattern letters here".

Comment: @k314159 yes, you are right. But I didn't "recommend" anything, just pointed to an example of documentation. My point was that just feeding the code and not answering the actual question is not useful.

Comment: Are you asking how to parse a date when you _know_ what format it will be in? Or how to _identify_ the format of a string that you think contains a date? The question _looks_ like it's asking the latter, but the answers (and your acceptance) suggest the former. If so, perhaps the title and question could be tweaked to make it clear?

Comment: then what will be question. I'll make the change to more descriptive,

Comment: My question is how to identify the format of a string that contains a date..

Comment: This looks totally impossible. A common format is "12/4/2022". This could mean either 12th of April or 4th of December, depending on your locale. It's impossible to recognise the pattern with a date like this. You just need to know the pattern to being with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
private fun getFormatDate(date: String): ZonedDateTime {
    val dateTimeFormatter =
        DateTimeFormatter
            .ofPattern("MMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss a")
            .withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()) // or some other zone that you would like to use
            .withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH)
    return ZonedDateTime.parse(date, dateTimeFormatter)
}
```

Note that it is important that you do `.withZone` which specifies the zone that the `ZonedDateTime` is going to have, and also `.withLocale`, so that the parser interprets things like "May" and "PM" in the correct language.

[Try It Online](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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)

[See all the pattern letters here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns)

Comment: Just a detail. A bit simpler (at least in my head), pass `Locale.ENGLISH` as a second argument to `ofPattern()`, and we don't need the call to `withLocale()`.